# how can I call dgemm in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, linear-algebra, blas

How can I call blas dgemm in Excel VBA?  My blas is Rblas.dll from an R installation.
If I put a breakpoint before the subroutine ends and go to the immediate window

```
?c(0,0),c(0,1),c(1,0),c(1,1)
```

gives

```
1 0 0 0
```

I would expect to get 13 16 29 36

Here is my code.

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub dgemm_ Lib "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\Rblas.dll" _
(ByVal transa As String, _
ByVal transb As String, _
ByRef m As Integer, _
ByRef n As Integer, _
ByRef k As Integer, _
ByRef alpha As Double, _
ByRef a As Double, _
ByRef lda As Integer, _
ByRef b As Double, _
ByRef ldb As Integer, _
ByRef beta As Double, _
ByRef c As Double, _
ByRef ldc As Integer)

Sub test_dgemm()
Dim alpha, beta As Double
Dim a(0 To 1, 0 To 1), b(0 To 1, 0 To 1), c(0 To 1, 0 To 1) As Double
Dim m, n, k, lda, ldb, ldc As Integer

a(0, 0) = 1
a(0, 1) = 2
a(1, 0) = 3
a(1, 1) = 4

b(0, 0) = 1
b(0, 1) = 2
b(1, 0) = 3
b(1, 1) = 4

c(0, 0) = 1
c(0, 1) = 2
c(1, 0) = 3
c(1, 1) = 4

m = 2
n = 2
k = 2
lda = 2
ldb = 2
ldc = 2
alpha = 1
beta = 0
transa = "N"
transb = "N"
Call dgemm_(transa, transb, m, n, k, alpha, a(0, 0), lda, b(0, 0), ldb, beta, c(0, 0), ldc)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The dim statements are wrong, and are making a() and b() arrays of variants.  Also, m, n, k, lda, ldb are not being dimmed integers, nor is alpha a double.

Here is how the arrays of doubles should be dimmed:

```
Dim a() As Double
Dim b() As Double
Dim c() As Double
ReDim a(0 To 1, 0 To 1), b(0 To 1, 0 To 1), c(0 To 1, 0 To 1)
```